# How to fix error about Import dlib on AWS Lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, dlib

I want to use dlib on AWS Lambda.

I use serverless framework(runtime is python3.6). I import dlib package using serverless-python-requirements plugins. 
It works very well at local  `$ serverless invoke local -f function`. But, when I deploy it and use inovek `$ serverless invoke -f function`, It makes errors.

#### serverless.yml's code

```
plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux
```

#### requirements.txt

```
boto3==1.9.135
botocore==1.12.135
Pillow==6.0.0
dlib==19.17.0
docutils==0.14
imutils==0.5.2
jmespath==0.9.4
numpy==1.16.3
opencv-python==4.1.0.25
python-dateutil==2.8.0
s3transfer==0.2.0
six==1.12.0
urllib3==1.24.2
```

#### error log of lamda aws

```
Unable to import module 'handler': libpng16.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Could you tell me the way to use dlib on aws lambda...

Comment: Hi- can you confirm that you are you using cross-compiling? https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-python-requirements#cross-compiling

Comment: Yes, I am using cross-compiling. 

  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux